# Saindo do loop while

Tags: c

**Estou fazendo um programa que seria um jogo de tabuleiro que quando todos os 4 jogadores chegarem na casa 100 o programa para, entretanto o meu código não está parando no 100:**

````
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



int main(){
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
 int i;
 int aux;
 int jogador[4] ={1,2,3,4};
 int pos[4] = {0,0,0,0};
 int volta[10];
 int avanca[10];
 srand(time(NULL));

 while(pos[i] != 100){     
   for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      aux= rand()%7;
      if(aux == 0){
        aux= rand()%7;
        pos[i] +=  aux;
        printf("\n\tJogador %d joga novamente\n", jogador[i] );
        printf("\njogador: %d -> jogada: %d -> posicao: %d \n", jogador[i], aux, pos[i]);
        } else {
            pos[i] +=  aux;
            printf("\njogador: %d -> jogada: %d -> posicao: %d \n", jogador[i], aux,pos[i]);
         }
      }
    }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

O teste da condição do while está incorreto:

```
while(pos[i] != 100)
```

Não testa todas as posições do array e se algum jogador tiver a posição um valor acima de 100 então ele também não vai parar no loop porque valores acima de 100 são diferentes de 100. O correto é testar cada posição e verificar se o valor já atingiu 100 ou mais.

Reescrevi seu código e incluí uma função para verificar se algum jogador já venceu depois de cada rodada:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool venceu(int pos[], int quantos) {
        int venceu = false;
        for (int i = 0;i < quantos;i++) 
                if (pos[i] >= 100)
                    venceu = true;
        return venceu;
}

int main(){
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
 int i = 0;
 int aux;
 int jogador[4] ={1,2,3,4};
 int pos[4] = {0,0,0,0};
 int volta[10];
 int avanca[10];
 srand(time(NULL));

 while(!venceu(pos, 4)) {     
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      aux= rand()%7;
      while(aux == 0){
        aux= rand()%7;
      }
      printf("\n\tJogador %d joga novamente\n", jogador[i] );
      pos[i] +=  aux;
      printf("\njogador: %d -> jogada: %d -> posicao: %d \n", jogador[i], aux,pos[i]);
      }
    }
 //system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá, mas agora o loop entende que todo jogador deve repetir a jogada. Fiz uma arquitetura para facilitar a leitura do que é necessário fazer mas estou com problemas para parar quando todos os quatro jogadores estiverem no 100 e para avançar e retornar de acordo com a posição que o jogador estiver. Vou mandar o diagrama que fiz: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKgyd.png